# SPARQL Query Printing Enumerate Class with JENA JAVA

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, ontology, protege

I made this owl model. There is two classes Sensor and Location, and Location is enumerated class.

```
:Sensor rdf:type owl:Class;
:Location rdf:type owl:Class ;
                 owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                                       owl:oneOf ( :Bathroom
                                                   :Bedroom
                                                 )
                                     ] .
:hasLocation rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                    rdfs:domain [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                                  :Sensor
                                ] ;
                    rdfs:range :Location .
:Bathing rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                         ADLOntology:Bathing .
:Bathroom rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                          ADLOntology:Location .
:Window rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                           :Sensor ;
                  :hasLocation :Bedroom;
                  :hasId "55"^^xsd:int ; .
```

I am trying to get the location of each sensors with their id-number. I wrote my query in Protege and it works fine. But, on JENA it's printing null for the location. I used the **Resource** to print the sensor, but for the location it prints null. I couldn't figure it out the properer way to print the location.

```
String file = "C:/users/src/data.ttl";
Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel(file);
String queryString = "PREFIX : <http://semanticweb.org/sensor#>" +
                     "SELECT ?sensor ?location" +
                     "WHERE {?sensor :hasId \"55"\^^xsd:int." +
                             "?sensor :hasLocation ?location}";
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)) {
          ResultSet result = qexec.execSelect();
          for ( ; result.hasNext(); ) {
                  QuerySolution soln = result.nextSolution();
                  Resource sensor= soln.getResource("sensor");
                  Resource location = soln.getResource("location");
                  System.out.println("Sensor" + sensor);
                  System.out.println("Location" + location);
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with enumeration in OWL.

The query simply looks for mappings in the RDF graph. In your example, it will work once you carefully check **how** the SPARQL query is generated. Note, that you concatenate the String in Java and either line breaks or spaces have to be used. Your query is missing both after the `?location` variable in the SELECT part, thus, it will result in `?locationWHERE`.

Solutions:

Add missing space, i.e.

```java
String queryString = "PREFIX : <http://semanticweb.org/sensor#>" +
                     "SELECT ?sensor ?location " +
                     "WHERE {?sensor :hasId \"55"\^^xsd:int." +
                             "?sensor :hasLocation ?location}";
```

or line break

```java
String queryString = "PREFIX : <http://semanticweb.org/sensor#>" +
                     "SELECT ?sensor ?location\n" +
                     "WHERE {?sensor :hasId \"55"\^^xsd:int." +
                             "?sensor :hasLocation ?location}";
```

Comment: Thanks so much, is there any good tutorials, you can recommend